# tengo problemas con la API de la Nasa

Tags: java, json, gson

Estaba intentando acceder a la API de la Nasa para obtener la información de los asteroides que van a pasar cerca de la Tierra.

Para ello estoy haciendo colecciones dentro de otras para poder acceder al nivel en el que se ordenen diferentes asteroides por fecha (adjunto enlace de la api para mostrar un ejemplo del JSON: https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2022-10-1&end_date=2022-10-5&api_key=) .

El caso es que en mi código no consigo pasar a los near_earth_object que se ordenan por fecha(aunque está guardado como String). ¿Qué podría hacer?

```
try {
    URL apiNasa = new URL(
                "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2022-10-1&end_date=2022-10-5&api_key=<API KEY>");

    BufferedReader lectorDeLaNasa = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiNasa.openStream()));
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.setPrettyPrinting();
    builder.setDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
    Gson gson = builder.create();



    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Asteroide>> object = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Asteroide>>();
    object = gson.fromJson(lectorDeLaNasa, TreeMap.class);

    System.out.println(object.get("near_earth_objects"));
        
    ArrayList<Asteroide> g=object.get("near_earth_objects");
        
    /*Asteroide a1 = new Asteroide();
    String fechaA1 = "" + LocalDate.of(LocalDateTime.now().getYear(), LocalDateTime.now().getMonthValue(),
            LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(fechaA1);

    if (object.containsKey(fechaA1)) {
        ArrayList<Asteroide> ast = new ArrayList<Asteroide>();
        object.put(fechaA1, ast);
    }
    object.get(fechaA1).add(a1);

    System.out.println("ddddddd");*/

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ¿En en el objeto `g` no tienes un `ArrayList` de todos los elementos que hay en `near_earth_objects`? No veo que hagas ninguna prueba con respecto a `g`. Convendría que nos muestres lo que hay en tu clase `Asteroide`. Por cierto, estás exponiendo tu API KEY en la pregunta. Considera evitar compartir información sensible cuando plantees preguntas aquí.

Comment: Es que cuando intento igualar el objeto g al contenido de near_earth_objects deja de compilar,ahí está mi duda

Comment: Es que no tienes que hacer eso. Si tus clases están bien diseñadas, Gson te va a crear objetos con el contenido del JSON que ha respondido la API. ¿Qué hay en tu clase `Asteroide`? ¿Qué muestra una depuración de `object`?